# I get at best 200Mbps with my WiFi6 router, should at least be 600Mbps according to the standard

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a 1Gbps internet link confirmed with a wired connected PC. The WiFi router is a Netgear Blackhawk RAX20.

When I use my devices (iPhone, iPad, MacBook) I get at best 200Mbps.

Running a WiFi diagnostic with the MacBook it reports that the WiFi router is 802.11ax and the speed is a bit over 200Mbps.

According to the specs of 802.11ax, I would expect to see at least 600Mbps.

Is this normal?

EDIT: According to [this article](https://www.cnet.com/home/internet/how-fast-is-wi-fi-6/) I should see at least 1Gbps. I only see around 200Mbps. Could it be the interference with the neighbors? I'm living in an apartment, not a house.

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting at 5Ghz or 6Ghz? If you can, disable the 2.4Ghz to force a 5Ghz or 6Ghz connection; if you are connected at 2.4Ghz that might explain the slowdown. What about the wired connection? What speed do you get when you directly connect to the router or modem? Basically I would recommend breaking down the connection piece by piece to track down the source of the  issue.

Comment: Just because 802.11ax claims that you *might* be able to get 600Mbps doesn't mean you will. Wireless is subject to interference by other networks, random electronics such as microwave ovens, cordless phones, bluetooth devices, baby monitors as well as other random things such as solar flare activity and the phase of the moon. Other devices on the same wireless network *might* also force the network down to a common speed. Try turning off every other device on the wireless network and see if you get full speed.

Comment: 600Mbps with WiFi 6 is only possible in perfect conditions inside of a RF isolation chamber. 802.11ax is WiFi 6 which does not support the more capable 6 GHz frequency that WiFi 6E supports. I have no idea why anyone is asking about 6 GHz since it’s not applicable to your hardware.

Comment: Can your _devices_ do Wi-Fi 6? There’s hundreds of iPhone, iPad and MacBook models, each with different specs.

Comment: Thank-you all for your comments. I tested with a macbook air M2, an iPad Pro 11", and iPhone 13 promax. They should all support wifi6 as they are recent. I have also an internet router from my ISP which also support wifi6 and I see similar performance even with only one device connected through wifi. I made sure to use 5Ghz on the netgear wifi access point. Unfortunately I have close neighbours and no RF isolated room to test the speed in optimal conditions. All Apple devices are wifi only and its a bit frustrating I can't use the full internet connection speed.

Comment: are you talking about WiFi or about your internet connection?

Comment: 802.11ax specifies "max speed 600–9608 Mbit/s" - that doesn't mean the minimum speed is *at least 600*

Comment: @jsotola WiFi speed. Internet speed is 1Gbps download and 600Mbps upload with optic fiber.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the issue and now get 720Mbps on average in the next room. The problem was due to a misconfiguration.

To get access to the extended configuration options, one has to connect a laptop with an Ethernet cable to one of the router ports, then connect to `https://192.168.1.1` with a browser. After using the credentials specified when configuring the router, we get access to some finer grained configuration parameters.

There is a parameter specifying the maximum speed in 2.4GHz and 5GHz. Both were on 280Mbps. I set the 5GHz to the maximum value which is 1200Mbps. I also switched from 20MHz to 80MHz (4 channels), the maximum.

It is also possible to change the default 5GHz channel to pick one that is not in conflict with a neighbor.

While seeking a solution, I bought the WiFi Explorer Lite macOS app to get a better view on the WiFi neighborhood. This is how I noticed that my Netgear was configured by default to a maximum speed of 284Mbps.

A last thing I changed is to configure my ISP's WiFi 5 router with the same SSID and password so that my devices may switch between them for optimal speed when I move in the house. The switching is not in a snap, but good enough.

Problem solved.

I ordered a TP-Link EAP653 which should be twice faster. We'll see.